# Cat 7 HEUI pump failure incidence rate

Tags: engine, diesel, fuel-injectors, failure-modes

Not exactly a car engine, but I am wondering if anyone has seen any statistics or guidance on Cat 7 HEUI pump failures?

The pump compresses engine oil which is then delivered to the diesel injectors to power them for injecting and atomizing the fuel.  When the pump fails it tends to take out the injectors with metal particulates.

The engine and HEUI pump have been out a while (20 years) and tend to be seen in older units, like school buses, delivery trucks, RVs, boats and other applications.

General advice for avoiding HEUI pump problems includes more frequent oil and filter

changes. I am looking for statistics or published material on the frequency, avoidance and other preventative measures.

Comment: One bit of contention here with what you've stated. You cannot compress a liquid. You may want to update your question.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it **is** compressible, see https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/5/jresv5n5p985_A2b.pdf  But, for the failure of the pump then the quality of the oil does come into play, as well as the points you make in your question about change frequency. The grade of filter will also make a difference, but fitting a higher grade filter can change the pressure drop across it...

Comment: @SolarMike - Generally, physics tells us *liquids are not compressible*. The amount of actual compressibility of liquids is so small, it becomes moot. Nevertheless, we aren't talking about compressing the liquid, we're talking about *pressurizing* the liquid. This makes a portion of the question incorrect, which is what I'm trying to have corrected.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 see this https://www.jstor.org/stable/44472014?seq=1 and then think about your use of terms like pressure and compressibility BTW both of the references are american...

Comment: @SolarMike - Thank you for your well intentioned advice. I just wish it was placed correctly. We aren't talking about the compressibility of fuels here. We're talking about pressurizing oil so it can inject the fuel. I guess you really didn't try to read the question, but would rather just prattle on about things which have no bearing. No worries. Again, what you've posted really has no bearing. Please try to stay on subject.

Comment: My statement was that the engine oil is compressed...  That statement stands. While the phase of liquids tend to be less compressible than gases, they are nevertheless compressible. Hydraulic jacks work that way. So do black holes.